# https://example.com opens a BIN file for download and not page content

Tags: linux, wordpress, nginx, ssl-certificate, hhvm

I installed a SSL certificate on my server in order to be used with wordpress. I followed manual from https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9419/0/nginx where my certificate is from.

However, when I open my site: https://example.com a `BIN file` is being shown for downloading instead of the page content being loaded and displayed.

The content of that very strange file is the following:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything,   
but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

I use Nginx/HHVM and rund wordpress on it.

Here is my `default` file from `/etc/nginx/sites-available`

```
# You may add here your
# server {
#   ...
# }
# statements for each of your virtual hosts to this file

##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;


root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name localhost;
include hhvm.conf;


location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
}

# Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
#location /RequestDenied {
#   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
#}

#error_page 404 /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
#error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#location = /50x.html {
#   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
#}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
#   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
#
#   # With php5-cgi alone:
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#   # With php5-fpm:
#   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
#   fastcgi_index index.php;
#   include fastcgi_params;
#}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#   deny all;
#}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#   listen 8000;
#   listen somename:8080;
#   server_name somename alias another.alias;
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
server {
listen 443;
server_name localhost;

root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;


ssl on;
ssl_certificate /usr/share/nginx/sslkeys/cert_chain.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /usr/share/nginx/sslkeys/privatekey.key;

ssl_session_timeout 5m;

ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its downloading the php file. You need to configure fastcgi to execute php scripts. You have some of the relevant config, but its commented out. Here is a good place to start: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/